# The components of basis vectors in linear algebra under a change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra, change-of-basis

If I choose a non-orthonormal basis for $\Bbb{R}^2$, I have to label the basis vectors by their components. But doing this requires me to specify the components of one of the basis vectors *relative* to that of the other one. For instance if I take the standard $(0,1)$, $(1,0)$ basis vectors and double the length of one of them, is there not ambiguity in the "unit" length? For instance the basis is now $(0,2)$, $(1,0)$, but could I equally define them as $(0,1)$, $(0.5,0)$?

My *guess* at the resolution is that when you move into a new basis, you redefine the "unit" component length to be $1$ in each direction. So that the vector $(1,1)$ corresponds to different vectors in two different bases. And my mistake comes from talking about the new basis *relative* to the old basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your guess is correct. The notation $(x, y)$ is meaningless without reference to a chosen basis.

If you choose a basis $v_1, v_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $(1, 2)$ denotes the vector $v_1+2v_2$.

If you choose a basis $u_1, u_2$ of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $(1, 2)$ denotes the vector $u_1+2u_2$. This can be a completely different vector from $v_1+2v_2$.

> If I choose a non-orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$, I have to label the basis vectors by their components. But doing this requires me to specify the components of one of the basis vectors *relative* to that of the other one.

This is not true. You are specifying the components relative to the standard basis. Therefore $(0,2), (1, 0)$ is not the same basis as $(0, 1), \left (\frac 12, 0 \right)$.

Comment: Solved, thanks!